# Problem parsing JSON file - fields not stored correctly

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a JSON file that I'm trying to parse. My script has a few print statements to check if I'm parsing the various fields correctly. It appears to be that way for `ids` and `ip_metadata[ip]` within the `for` loop. However, when I print out the entire dictionary at the end, the `ids` list is always the last ones. Only `ids` has this problem, the other fields were stored correctly. I can't see why `ids` isn't stored correctly.

JSON file:

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "ip": "1.2.3.4",
            "cty": {
                "country": "US",
                "organization": "ABC"
            },
            "info": {
                "p": [
                    {
                        "id": 123,
                        "grp": "A"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 234,
                        "grp": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 345,
                        "grp": "C"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 456,
                        "grp": "D"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "ip": "2.3.4.5",
            "cty": {
                "country": "US",
                "organization": "ABC"
            },
            "info": {
                "p": [
                    {
                        "id": 111,
                        "grp": "A"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 222,
                        "grp": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 333,
                        "grp": "C"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 444,
                        "grp": "D"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "ip": "1.2.3.1",
            "cty": {
                "country": "AU",
                "organization": "ABC"
            },
            "info": {
                "p": [
                    {
                        "id": 222,
                        "grp": "A"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 333,
                        "grp": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 444,
                        "grp": "C"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "ip": "10.2.3.4",
            "cty": {
                "country": "US",
                "organization": "DDD"
            },
            "info": {
                "p": [
                    {
                        "id": 555,
                        "grp": "A"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 666,
                        "grp": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 777,
                        "grp": "C"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 888,
                        "grp": "D"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "status": "ok"
}
```

My python script is

```
import json
import glob
from collections import defaultdict

ip_metadata = defaultdict(list)

def main():
    for json_file in glob.glob("test_input/test_json.json"):
        with open(json_file, "r") as fin:
            ids = []
            json_data = json.load(fin)
            if json_data["count"] > 0:
                for data in json_data['data']:
                    ip = data['ip']
                    country = data['cty']['country']
                    organization = data['cty']['organization']
                    ids[:] = []
                    ids_2 = data['info']['p']
                    for idss in ids_2:
                        id = idss['id']
                        grp = idss['grp']
                        ids.append((id,grp))
                    
                    print(ids)
                    ip_metadata[ip].append((country,organization,ids))
                    print(ip_metadata[ip])
                    
    print("=============================")
    for k, v in ip_metadata.items():
        print(k,v)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is

```
[(123, 'A'), (234, 'B'), (345, 'C'), (456, 'D')]
[('US', 'ABC', [(123, 'A'), (234, 'B'), (345, 'C'), (456, 'D')])]
[(111, 'A'), (222, 'B'), (333, 'C'), (444, 'D')]
[('US', 'ABC', [(111, 'A'), (222, 'B'), (333, 'C'), (444, 'D')])]
[(222, 'A'), (333, 'B'), (444, 'C')]
[('AU', 'ABC', [(222, 'A'), (333, 'B'), (444, 'C')])]
[(555, 'A'), (666, 'B'), (777, 'C'), (888, 'D')]
[('US', 'DDD', [(555, 'A'), (666, 'B'), (777, 'C'), (888, 'D')])]
=============================
1.2.3.4 [('US', 'ABC', [(555, 'A'), (666, 'B'), (777, 'C'), (888, 'D')])]
2.3.4.5 [('US', 'ABC', [(555, 'A'), (666, 'B'), (777, 'C'), (888, 'D')])]
1.2.3.1 [('AU', 'ABC', [(555, 'A'), (666, 'B'), (777, 'C'), (888, 'D')])]
10.2.3.4 [('US', 'DDD', [(555, 'A'), (666, 'B'), (777, 'C'), (888, 'D')])]
```

Comment: Why are you doing `ids[:] = []`? It empties the contents from `ids`

Comment: @rdas It's because I only want to store the `id` and `grp` for each `ip` within the `data` block. Otherwise `ids` would contain all `id` and `grp` for all `ip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by removing the `ids = []` line under the `open()` line, and replace `ids[:] = []` with `ids = []` instead. I don't quite understand why this fixes things, because I don't know why the value of `ids` would replace previously stored values of `ids` of different keys. But it works now.